# Javascript Dynamically Created Event Handlers Disappear once another is added

Tags: javascript, event-handling, addeventlistener, dom-events

I have an ordered list that I want to have items disappear from when clicked.

I have the following javascript code:

```
<script>
    let halls = new Set();

    function rm() {
        halls.delete((this.id).substring(0,this.id.length-4));
        document.getElementById(this.id).remove();
    }
    function setEventHandler(obj, name, fn) {
        if (typeof obj == "string") {
            obj = document.getElementById(obj);
        }
        if (obj.addEventListener) {
            return(obj.addEventListener(name, fn));
        } else if (obj.attachEvent) {
            return(obj.attachEvent("on" + name, function() {return(fn.call(obj));}));
        }
    }

    function addHall() {
        let oldSize = halls.size;
        let chosen = document.getElementById("hall2").value;
        halls.add(chosen);
        if (oldSize != halls.size) {
            document.getElementById("fillHall").innerHTML += `<li id="${chosen}List" name="${chosen}" >${chosen}</li>`;
            setEventHandler(chosen + "List", "click", rm);
        }
    };

    document.getElementById("hall2").onchange = addHall;
</script>
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?? How do I keep the event handler that will remove the list item?

I know my code is sloppy :/ sorry

Thanks

Comment: can you please provide html code as well?

Comment: Why on earth are you falling back to `attachEvent()`? If a browser doesn't support `addEventListener()`, it _certainly_ won't support `Set` or template literals.

Comment: @Nirali is there a specific portion of it you'd like to see? there's some personally identifying material on the html...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I'm not sure - this is based on code I found online. I struggled for a long time to get these list items to delete - currently the most recently added list item deletes, but not the rest. Part of the struggle was getting the function associated with the event to know which list item called it, and this solution seemed to work better than anything else I tried